# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project siriproject: Compilation failure

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-2, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.1 and JDK 1.8. When I tried Build war file using " clean install spring-boot:repackage " command in the eclipse -> run as -> maven build . throwing following error.

> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project siriproject: Compilation failure     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation failure   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>     ... 20 more

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>siriusxm</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
            <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>


    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>com.abc.ondb.siriproject.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</generateDirectory>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>https://api-ext-test.siriproject.com/ESB/CreatePromotionRegistrationByWin/v_1?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>    
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the env parameters and java related properties in maven configuration.
Also please run the the command with -X option to see the debug messages from maven

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I have a simlar problem

Comment: I also had similar issues and the root cause was with typo that related to env params. For example, java installation path. You have to use -X option to see the debug messages from maven

Comment: I tried the build from eclipse using its own embedded maven but the standalone config filled and it worked just fine so I know it’s not that but thanks for the suggestion and your time

Comment: I dont have an answer as there a number of situations that give very similar results.Look carefully at the actual exception, using -X and -e to assist you. in my case totally stripping the pom to nothing (and commenting out the code where each dependency is used) helped as did slowly removing each class. In my case one homemade jar in my dependencies was causing the issue. I still dont understand why "invalid path" comes up, but at least I know **where** the problem is now.NB, running a maven build in Eclipse gave a better error  ("index 28") than command line maven did.

Comment: i found this [link](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/issues/62#issuecomment-887532561)  where a bug in the JDT handling of bundle and external classpaths closely mirrors the stack trace that I am seeing. in case of link death, it ws https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/issues/62#issuecomment-887532561